# how to manage secure application API keys with Chef

Tags: git, chef

I have an application I'd like to provision a VPS server for using Chef.  My application uses a file that sets up environment variables containing secure API keys for various third party services.  I could just manually add this to the server, but it seems like something I should automate with Chef.  However, I plan on keeping my "kitchen", or set of cookbooks for provisioning the application server, in a Git repo. I don't want to add these API keys to the repo.  What's the best way to keep these out of the kitchen's repo but available to Chef for provisioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [chef-vault](https://github.com/Nordstrom/chef-vault)!

It uses the PKI that you already have through Chef Client's certificates and is way more flexible and easier to manage than [encrypted data bags](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_data_bags.html#encrypt-a-data-bag).

There's also a very detailed post by [Joshua Timberman](https://superuser.com/users/90/jtimberman) entitled [Managing Secrets with Chef Vault](http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2013/09/10/managing-secrets-with-chef-vault/).

Comment: Thank you very much!  That's exactly what I was looking for.